# Incremental but complete parsing with PyParsing?

Tags: parsing, python-2.7, pyparsing

I'm using PyParsing to parse some rather large text files with a C-like format ([braces and semicolons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages_by_type#Curly-bracket_languages) and all that).

PyParsing works just great, but it is slow and consumes a very large amount of memory due to the size of my files.

Because of this, I wanted to try to implement an **incremental** parsing approach wherein I'd parse the top-level elements of the source file one-by-one. The `scanString` method of pyparsing seems like the obvious way to do this. However, I want to make sure that there is no invalid/unparseable text in-between the sections parsed by `scanString`, and can't figure out a good way to do this.

Here's a simplified example that shows the problem I'm having:

```
sample="""f1(1,2,3); f2_no_args( );
# comment out: foo(4,5,6);
bar(7,8);
this should be an error;
baz(9,10);
"""

from pyparsing import *

COMMENT=Suppress('#' + restOfLine())
SEMI,COMMA,LPAREN,RPAREN = map(Suppress,';,()')

ident = Word(alphas, alphanums+"_")
integer = Word(nums+"+-",nums)

statement = ident("fn") + LPAREN + Group(Optional(delimitedList(integer)))("arguments") + RPAREN + SEMI

p = statement.ignore(COMMENT)

for res, start, end in p.scanString(sample):
    print "***** (%d,%d)" % (start, end)
    print res.dump()
```

Output:

```
***** (0,10)
['f1', ['1', '2', '3']]
- arguments: ['1', '2', '3']
- fn: f1
***** (11,25)
['f2_no_args', []]
- arguments: []
- fn: f2_no_args
***** (53,62)
['bar', ['7', '8']]
- arguments: ['7', '8']
- fn: bar
***** (88,98)
['baz', ['9', '10']]
- arguments: ['9', '10']
- fn: baz
```

The ranges returned by `scanString` have gaps due to unparsed text between them ((0,10),(11,25),(53,62),(88,98)). Two of these gaps are whitespace or comments, which should not trigger an error, but one of them (`this should be an error;`) contains unparsable text, which I want to catch.

**Is there a way to use pyparsing to parse a file incrementally while still ensuring that the entire input could be parsed with the specified parser grammar?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I came up with what seems to be a pretty decent solution after a brief discussion [on the PyParsing users' mailing list](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.pyparsing.user/673).

I modified the `ParserElement.parseString` method slightly to come up with `parseConsumeString`, which does about what I want. This version calls `ParserElement._parse` followed by `ParserElement.preParse` repeatedly.

Here is code to monkey-patch `ParserElement` with the `parseConsumeString` method:

```
from pyparsing import ParseBaseException, ParserElement

def parseConsumeString(self, instring, parseAll=True, yieldLoc=False):
    '''Generator version of parseString which does not try to parse
    the whole string at once.

    Should be called with a top-level parser that could parse the
    entire string if called repeatedly on the remaining pieces.
    Instead of:

        ZeroOrMore(TopLevel)).parseString(s ...)

    Use:

        TopLevel.parseConsumeString(s ...)

    If yieldLoc==True, it will yield a tuple of (tokens, startloc, endloc).
    If False, it will yield only tokens (like parseString).

    If parseAll==True, it will raise an error as soon as a parse
    error is encountered. If False, it will return as soon as a parse
    error is encountered (possibly before yielding any tokens).'''

    if not self.streamlined:
        self.streamline()
        #~ self.saveAsList = True
    for e in self.ignoreExprs:
        e.streamline()
    if not self.keepTabs:
        instring = instring.expandtabs()
    try:
        sloc = loc = 0
        while loc<len(instring):
            # keeping the cache (if in use) across loop iterations wastes memory (can't backtrack outside of loop)
            ParserElement.resetCache()
            loc, tokens = self._parse(instring, loc)
            if yieldLoc:
                yield tokens, sloc, loc
            else:
                yield tokens
            sloc = loc = self.preParse(instring, loc)
    except ParseBaseException as exc:
        if not parseAll:
            return
        elif ParserElement.verbose_stacktrace:
            raise
        else:
            # catch and re-raise exception from here, clears out pyparsing internal stack trace
            raise exc

def monkey_patch():
    ParserElement.parseConsumeString = parseConsumeString
```

Notice that I also moved the call to `ParserElement.resetCache` into each loop iteration. Because it's impossible to backtrack out of each loop, there's no need to retain the cache across iterations. This drastically reduce memory consumption when using PyParsing's [packrat caching](http://pyparsing-public.wikispaces.com/FAQs#Frequently%20Asked%20Questions-What%20the%20heck%20is%20%22packrat%20parsing%22?) feature. In my tests with a 10 MiB input file, peak memory consumption goes down from ~6G to ~100M peak, while running about 15-20% faster.