# pyparsing recursion of values list (ibm rhapsody)

Tags: python, recursion, pyparsing, rhapsody

Im building a parser for the IBM Rhapsody `sbs` file format. But unfortunately the recursion part won't work as expected. The rule `pp.Word(pp.printables + " ")` is probably the problem as it matches also `;` and `{}`. But at least `;` can also be part of the values.

```
import pyparsing as pp
import pprint


TEST = r"""{ foo
    - key = bla;
    - value = 1243; 1233; 1235;
    - _hans = "hammer
    time";
    - HaMer = 765; 786; 890;
    - value = "
    #pragma LINK_INFO DERIVATIVE \"mc9s12xs256\"
        ";
    - _mText = 12.11.2015::13:20:0;
    - value = "war"; "fist";
    - _obacht = "fish,car,button";
    - _id = gibml c0d8-4535-898f-968362779e07;
    - bam = { boing
        - key = bla;
    }
    { boing
        - key = bla;
    }
}
"""


def flat(loc, toks):
    if len(toks[0]) == 1:
        return toks[0][0]

assignment = pp.Suppress("-") + pp.Word(pp.alphanums + "_") + pp.Suppress("=")

value = pp.OneOrMore(
    pp.Group(assignment + (
        pp.Group(pp.OneOrMore(
            pp.QuotedString('"', escChar="\\", multiline=True) +
            pp.Suppress(";"))).setParseAction(flat) |
        pp.Word(pp.alphas) + pp.Suppress(";") |
        pp.Word(pp.printables + " ")
    ))
)

expr = pp.Forward()

expr = pp.Suppress("{") + pp.Word(pp.alphas) + (
    value | (assignment + expr) | expr
) + pp.Suppress("}")
expr = expr.ignore(pp.pythonStyleComment)


print TEST
pprint.pprint(expr.parseString(TEST).asList())
```

Output:

```
% python prase.py                                                    
{ foo
    - key = bla;
    - value = 1243; 1233; 1235;
    - _hans = "hammer
    time";
    - HaMer = 765; 786; 890;
    - value = "
    #pragma LINK_INFO DERIVATIVE \"mc9s12xs256\"
        ";
    - _mText = 12.11.2015::13:20:0;
    - value = "war"; "fist";
    - _obacht = "fish,car,button";
    - _id = gibml c0d8-4535-898f-968362779e07;
    - bam = { boing
        - key = bla;
    }
    { boing
        - key = bla;
    }
}

['foo',
 ['key', 'bla'],
 ['value', '1243; 1233; 1235;'],
 ['_hans', 'hammer\n    time'],
 ['HaMer', '765; 786; 890;'],
 ['value', '\n    #pragma LINK_INFO DERIVATIVE "mc9s12xs256"\n        '],
 ['_mText', '12.11.2015::13:20:0;'],
 ['value', ['war', 'fist']],
 ['_obacht', 'fish,car,button'],
 ['_id', 'gibml c0d8-4535-898f-968362779e07;'],
 ['bam', '{ boing'],
 ['key', 'bla']]
```

Comment: Is there a typo in TEST? Should that last group after `- bam { boing etc. }`  be `- something = { boing \n- key =bla; }`?  It is difficult to see what this format is supposed to be, you have various OneOrMore's thrown in here and there. I think if you stopped and wrote a BNF first, things would be clearer.

Comment: Also I strongly advise against expressions that match too much, like `pp.Word(printables + ' ')` - read up on the latest version of pyparsing's Word class, which includes the `excludeChars` argument so that, if you really need something like `Word(anything printable except ';')`, then write `Word(printables, excludeChars=';')`.

Comment: Sadly the format is right. A real example https://github.com/mansam/exploring-rhapsody/blob/master/LightSwitch/LightSwitch.rpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, that is one messy model format! I think this will get you close. I started out by trying to characterize what a valid value expression could be. I saw that each grouping could contain ';'-terminated attribute definitions, or '{}'-enclosed nested objects. Each object contained a leading identifier giving the object type.

The difficult issue was the very general token which I named 'value_word', which is pretty much any grouping of characters, as long as it is not a '-', '{', or '}'. The negative lookaheads in the definition of 'value_word' take care of this. I think a key issue here is that I was able to *not* include ' ' as a valid character in a 'value_word', but instead let pyparsing do its default whitespace-skipping with a potential for having one or more 'value_word's make up an 'attr_value'.

The final kicker (not found in your test case, but in the example you linked to) was this line for an attribute 'assignment':

```
            - m_pParent = ;
```

So the attr_value had to allow for an empty string also.

```
from pyparsing import *

LBRACE,RBRACE,SEMI,EQ,DASH = map(Suppress,"{};=-")

ident = Word(alphas + '_', alphanums+'_').setName("ident")
guid = Group('GUID' + Combine(Word(hexnums)+('-'+Word(hexnums))*4))
qs = QuotedString('"', escChar="\\", multiline=True)
character_literal = Combine("'" + oneOf(list(printables+' ')) + "'")
value_word = ~DASH + ~LBRACE + ~RBRACE + Word(printables, excludeChars=';').setName("value_word")

value_atom = guid | qs | character_literal | value_word

object_ = Forward()

attr_value = OneOrMore(object_) | Optional(delimitedList(Group(value_atom+OneOrMore(value_atom))|value_atom, ';')) + SEMI
attr_value.setName("attr_value")
attr_defn = Group(DASH + ident("name") + EQ + Group(attr_value)("value"))
attr_defn.setName("attr_defn")

object_ <<= Group(
    LBRACE + ident("type") +
    Group(ZeroOrMore(attr_defn | object_))("attributes") + 
    RBRACE
    )

object_.parseString(TEST).pprint()
```

For your test string it gives:

```
[['foo',
  [['key', ['bla']],
   ['value', ['1243', '1233', '1235']],
   ['_hans', ['hammer\n    time']],
   ['HaMer', ['765', '786', '890']],
   ['value', ['\n    #pragma LINK_INFO DERIVATIVE "mc9s12xs256"\n        ']],
   ['_mText', ['12.11.2015::13:20:0']],
   ['value', ['war', 'fist']],
   ['_obacht', ['fish,car,button']],
   ['_id', [['gibml', 'c0d8-4535-898f-968362779e07']]],
   ['bam', [['boing', [['key', ['bla']]]], ['boing', [['key', ['bla']]]]]]]]]
```

I added results names that might help in processing these structures. Using `object_.parseString(TEST).dump()` gives this output:

```
[['foo', [['key', ['bla']], ['value', ['1243', '1233', '1235']], ['_hans', ['hammer\n    time']], ...
[0]:
  ['foo', [['key', ['bla']], ['value', ['1243', '1233', '1235']], ['_hans', ['hammer\n    time']], ...
  - attributes: [['key', ['bla']], ['value', ['1243', '1233', '1235']], ['_hans', ['hammer...
    [0]:
      ['key', ['bla']]
      - name: key
      - value: ['bla']
    [1]:
      ['value', ['1243', '1233', '1235']]
      - name: value
      - value: ['1243', '1233', '1235']
    [2]:
      ['_hans', ['hammer\n    time']]
      - name: _hans
      - value: ['hammer\n    time']
    [3]:
      ['HaMer', ['765', '786', '890']]
      - name: HaMer
      - value: ['765', '786', '890']
    [4]:
      ['value', ['\n    #pragma LINK_INFO DERIVATIVE "mc9s12xs256"\n        ']]
      - name: value
      - value: ['\n    #pragma LINK_INFO DERIVATIVE "mc9s12xs256"\n        ']
    [5]:
      ['_mText', ['12.11.2015::13:20:0']]
      - name: _mText
      - value: ['12.11.2015::13:20:0']
    [6]:
      ['value', ['war', 'fist']]
      - name: value
      - value: ['war', 'fist']
    [7]:
      ['_obacht', ['fish,car,button']]
      - name: _obacht
      - value: ['fish,car,button']
    [8]:
      ['_id', [['gibml', 'c0d8-4535-898f-968362779e07']]]
      - name: _id
      - value: [['gibml', 'c0d8-4535-898f-968362779e07']]
        [0]:
          ['gibml', 'c0d8-4535-898f-968362779e07']
    [9]:
      ['bam', [['boing', [['key', ['bla']]]], ['boing', [['key', ['bla']]]]]]
      - name: bam
      - value: [['boing', [['key', ['bla']]]], ['boing', [['key', ['bla']]]]]
        [0]:
          ['boing', [['key', ['bla']]]]
          - attributes: [['key', ['bla']]]
            [0]:
              ['key', ['bla']]
              - name: key
              - value: ['bla']
          - type: boing
        [1]:
          ['boing', [['key', ['bla']]]]
          - attributes: [['key', ['bla']]]
            [0]:
              ['key', ['bla']]
              - name: key
              - value: ['bla']
          - type: boing
  - type: foo
```

It also successfully parses the linked example, once the leading version line is removed.

Comment: Nice. I added a handling for `negative number`, `date` and the leading `header` but than it worked great. I wasn't aware of the `NotAny (~)` operator but to sum it up, its all a `delimited list` or a `object`. I tried it on a larger (700kB) Model  and it took 25s to parse it. I forked your repo and i'm playing around with cython. For now i got it down to 18s. I will post my result to this repo https://github.com/delijati/pyparsing

Comment: Before going too far down a forking or cython road, try enabling packrat parsing. Doesn't always help, but for some recursive grammars, the results can be 10-100X.

Comment: Tried `pp.enablePackrat()` but the memory consumption went  
through the roof up to 4x. I read that calling `resetCache` helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591485/incremental-but-complete-parsing-with-pyparsing . Maybe replacing the cache with `lru_cache` which has a `maxsize` could also work.